# Ionic ios build not using location

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I have built an app in ionic2 that tracks the phone's current location. I have built it in android and works fine when the location is on but when I built it on iOS the app doesn't show on Privacy>Location Services and doesn't track the phone's current location.

```
const watchOptions = {
        enableHighAccurary: true,
        maximumAge:5000,
        timeout: 5000
    }
    if(state == 'login'){
        this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions).subscribe(pos => {
            if(pos.coords != undefined){
                console.log('tracking');
                this.firebaseApp.database().ref("LOCATION").child(this.user.$key).update({
                    lat: pos.coords.latitude,
                    lng: pos.coords.longitude,
                    timeStamp: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm A').toString(),
                    fName: this.user.fName,
                    lName: this.user.lName,
                    status: 'login'
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
    else{
        this.watch.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`-key and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`-key to `.plist`-file.

You find this file in "platforms/ios"

Comment: where do i get the plist file?

Comment: As stated in the comment, it's placed in your project folder -> platforms -> ios -> _app_name -> _app_name Plist.plist. Open with editor and add the following lines: `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key><string>Description</string><key> NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key><string>Description</string>`